# How to disable TRACE or change the log level in JBOSS EAP 7

Tags: jboss

i am getting lot of "TRACE" on my server log, because of which jboss start up is taking a lot of time, can somebody help to disable TRACE or change the log level ?

```
    yers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.9.CP,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base))
2019-02-20 15:37:05,413 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Loading class com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOM2Writer locally from Module "javax.wsdl4j.api:main" from local module loader @47d384ee (finder: local module finder @2d6a9952 (roots: /MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.9.CP,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base))
2019-02-20 15:37:05,414 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Attempting to define class com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml.DOM2Writer in Module "javax.wsdl4j.api:main" from local module loader @47d384ee (finder: local module finder @2d6a9952 (roots: /MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.9.CP,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base))
2019-02-20 15:37:05,414 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Attempting to define package com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml in Module "javax.wsdl4j.api:main" from local module loader @47d384ee (finder: local module finder @2d6a9952 (roots: /MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.9.CP,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base))
2019-02-20 15:37:05,414 TRACE [org.jboss.modules] (MSC service thread 1-2) Defined package com.ibm.wsdl.util.xml in Module "javax.wsdl4j.api:main" from local module loader @47d384ee (finder: local module finder @2d6a9952 (roots: /MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules,/MBANK1_APP/FE/PROFILE/jboss-eap-7.0/modules/system/layers/base/.overlays/layer-base-jboss-eap-7.0.
```

Comment: You need to configure the logging subsystem accordingly, but you should really read its documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/configuration_guide/logging_with_jboss_eap#about_logging_subsystem)

Comment: my standalone.xml is at INFO only :( ,  <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>

Comment: the log extract you have a problem with, is it displayed on the console or is it inside a file? The console-handler whose configuration you show only handles console output, if it's a file you should look into a file-handler

Comment: And you should probably reduce the log level on the logger side rather than on the handler side anyway, having TRACE level on org.jboss.modules is rarely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is solved after doing the below changes

In logging.properties`logger.level=INFO`

In standalone-full.xml

```
` <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
   </root-logger>`
```

Comment: I would suggest not editing the XML. You can use the web console or CLI to easily do this which will not require a restart. In CLI it's simply `/subsystem=logging/root-logger=ROOT:write-attribute(name=level, value=INFO)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change console log level in stanadalone.xml configuration file (For example to INFO) or from admine console in loggin part:

```
 <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:3.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
```